# How does this code that draws a stoplight with red, yellow and green lights work?

Tags: java

I'm having a lot of trouble grasping the concept of this example in my text book. The idea is to draw a stoplight with red, yellow and green lights. I have a couple of questions. I'm having trouble figuring out what part of the code does what.

1. Am I right to assume `cx` and `cy` are to figure out the center of the page?
2. Are `fx` and `fy` to figure out the center of the frame?
3. I don't know what `dy` does and why it's divided by 4 and not 3 for 3 lights and the `LAMP_RADIUS` totally confuses me.
4. On all three `add(createFilledCircle)` for red, yellow and green I don't understand how their position is calculated inside the stoplight frame.
5. In the method `createFilledCircle()` I don't understand `GOval circle = newGOval(x-r, y-r, 2 * r, 2 * r);`. I don't understand what `x-r` and `y-r` does and how that relates to position.

```java
import acm. graphics.*;
import acm. program.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawStoplight extends GraphicsProgram {

    public void run () {
        double cx = getWidth() / 2;
        double cy = getHeight() / 2; 
        double fx = cx - FRAME_WIDTH / 2; 
        double fy = cy- FRAME_HEIGHT / 2; 
        double dy = FRAME_HEIGHT / 4 + LAMP_RADIUS / 2; 
        GRect frame = new GRect(fx, fy, FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setFilled(true);
        frame.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        add(frame);
        add(createFilledCircle(cx, cy - dy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.RED));
        add(createFilledCircle(cx, cy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.YELLOW));
        add(createFilledCircle(cx, cy + dy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.GREEN));
    }

    private GOval createFilledCircle(double x, double y, double r, Color color){
        GOval circle = new GOval(x-r, y-r, 2 * r, 2 * r)
        circle.setColor(color);
        circle.setFilled(true);
        return circle;
    }

    private static final double FRAME_WIDTH = 50; 
    private static final double FRAME_HEIGHT = 100; 
    private static final double LAMP_RADIUS = 10; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. Am I right to assume cx and cy are to figure out the center of the page?
```

Yes

```
2. Are fx and fy to figure out the center of the frame?
```

Not exactly.  They are computing the upper left hand corner of the frame.  They start at the center and "back up" by half the frame size in each direction.

```
3. I don't know what dy does and why it's divided by 4 and not 3 for 3 lights and the LAMP_RADIUS totally confuses me.
```

Look farther down in the code.  `dy` is the vertical distance between lights.  The yellow light is drawn exactly at the center, the red is `dy` above, and the green is `dy` below.   The divisor is `4` because the author chose to align the bottom edge of the red light with a point 1/4 of the frame height from the top of the frame.  Similarly he chose to align the top of the green light with a point 1/4 of the frame height from the bottom.  He could have chosen many other ways of computing `dy`.

```
4. On all three add(createFilledCircle) for red, yellow and green I don't understand how their position is calculated inside the stoplight frame.
```

They all have the same x-coordinate: the center of the frame.  The y-coordinates are computed as explained in 3.  Remember in screen coordinates, the positive direction is down, so increasing y puts a light lower.  Decreasing puts it higher.

```
5. In the method createFilledCircle() I don't understand GOval circle = newGOval(x-r, y-r, 2 * r, 2 * r);. I don't understand what x-r and y-r does and how that relates to position.
```

Go read the manual definition of newGOval.  It inscribes an oval shape inside a rectangle.  The parameters are the upper left corner of the rectangle followed by the width and height.  So if (x,y) is the center, this is giving a box with diagonal (x-r, y-r) to (x+r, y+r).  When you inscribe an oval in that, you get a circle centered at (x,y) as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just plain forgot or didn't remember that the coordinates are calculated by the top left of the figures and circles. That was really confusing me about the calculations being done.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right to assume `cx` and `cy` are to figure out the center of the page?

Yes

> Are `fx` and `fy` to figure out the center of the frame?

No, they're the top-left coordinate

> I don't know what dy does and why it's divided by 4 and not 3 for 3 lights and the `LAMP_RADIUS` totally confuses me.

To fit three lights vertically inside a box you need one in the middle, one at 1/4 height, and one at 3/4 height - hence the division by four.  I'm unsure why the `LAMP_RADIUS` comes into it.  It appears to be what I'd normally call a "fudge factor" to make the lamps more widely spaced, i.e a figure that looks right, but without any good reason *why* it looks right...

> On all three `add(createFilledCircle)` for red, yellow and green I don't understand how their position is calculated inside the stoplight frame.

They're just vertically spaced by `dy`

> In the method `createFilledCircle()` I don't understand `GOval circle = newGOval(x-r, y-r, 2 * r, 2 * r);`. I don't understand what `x-r` and `y-r` does and how that relates to position.

The `GOval` puts a circle inside the box defined by the coordinates `(x - r, y - r)` with size `2r` - i.e a square of side-length `2r` centered on `(x, y)`

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I had a lot of trouble with this problem because I forgot that the top left is how the coordinates are calculated.